# Remove apt repository?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, add-apt-repository

Some while ago I may have accidentally added an apt repository with an invalid URL. Now, every time I run `sudo apt update`, the following error message shows at the bottom:

```
E: The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com (lsb_release Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I've tried using `sudo add-apt-repository --remove 'http://archive.canonical.com (lsb_release Release'`, after running the command there was no difference. How can I remove this url from my apt repository list?

Edit: The url `http://archive.canonical.com (lsb_release Release` is not found in my /etc/apt/sources.list

The following gist contains both the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` as well as the output of `sudo apt update`
https://gist.github.com/MrSiliconGuy/4ae2c649e5133f7edff012bfd6483d70

Edit: Turns out it was the line `deb http://archive.canonical.com/ (lsb_release -sc) partner`

You cannot have shell commands in your apt source file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repositories are stored in a file located at /etc/apt/sources.list.
You can edit that to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for responding. However, I cannot find the faulty url (or any third-party repositories for that matter) in my sources.list file. Here are the contents of my /etc/apt/sources.list
https://gist.github.com/MrSiliconGuy/4ae2c649e5133f7edff012bfd6483d70

Comment: Look on line 52 of your sources.list. You cannot use shell commands in this file. "(lsb_release -sc)" is an attempt to put a shell command in the file.

Comment: Replace `(lsb_release -sc)` in the file by output of command `lsb_release -sc`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using ubuntu 20, you can go to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

There you'll find the repositories that you add. Then just remove a file that cotains the name of the repository and run apt update again.

Answer (score 4):

Simple. Some times you'll go to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and wont find the repository that's misbehaving.

Solution is to use `-r` like so..

Line below is what you ran to add the repository that probably is no longer available / valid (abc & def in this case are just placeholders)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:abc/def
```

Remove it like so

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:abc/def
```

Now run `sudo apt update` again and all your problems should be gone!

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a terminal
2. Edit the sources.list file.
3. Save your changes.

Here's an example using the terminal-based nano text editor:

1. Open a terminal
2. `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

   - `sudo` because the file is owned by root (not you)
   - `nano` is the name of the application (text editor)
   - `/etc/apt/sources.list` is the complete path and filename
3. Use your arrow keys to move around the editor. Use your delete or backspace keys to delete the bad line.
4. Use CTRL+O to save your changes.
5. Use CTRL +X to exit the editor and return to a command prompt.