# xdg-desktop-portal-gtk conflict after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

In my Ubuntu 20.04, when I execute `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`, apt informs me that the package xdg-desktop-portal-gtk cannot be updated.
As a consequence, if I try `sudo apt reinstall xdg-desktop-portal-gtk` I get the message (in italian, but you can easily imagine what it means):

```
xdg-desktop-portal-gtk : Dipende: libgnome-desktop-3-18 (>= 3.17.92) ma non è installabile
```

If I run `sudo apt list -ua` I get:

```
xdg-desktop-portal-gtk/eoan 1.7.1-flatpak1~eoan amd64 [aggiornabile da: 1.6.0-1build1]
xdg-desktop-portal-gtk/focal,now 1.6.0-1build1 amd64 [installato, aggiornabile a: 1.7.1-flatpak1~eoan]
```

While the output of `apt-cache policy xdg-desktop-portal-gtk` is:

```
  Installato: 1.6.0-1build1
  Candidato:  1.7.1-flatpak1~eoan
  Tabella versione:
     1.7.1-flatpak1~eoan 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexlarsson/flatpak/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.6.0-1build1 500
        500 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Flatpak is installed from its official PPA.

How can I solve the conflict? Is there a chance to "block" one repository for this specific package in order to get it from the other one? If yes, which is the version that I should prefer?

Comment: I see one problem, http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexlarsson/ stops 19.10 and it should be covering to 20.04 which the maintainer hasn't covered yet.  Looks like you can email the maintainer asking when it will be updated for 20.04.

Comment: To block that repository you would have to remove it or comment it out.  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233064/remove-apt-repository

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I already know how to purge a ppa but I was tryng to understand how to avoid it, due to the fact that I want flatpak in my system... until I discovered that it exists in universe repository, I don't need to install it from PPA (and the version from universe repository is for focal version). So I've followed your suggestion, removed ppa and reinstalled flatpak from repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the idea [suggested by Terrance](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240244/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk-conflict-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-20-04?noredirect=1#comment2089463_1240244) I solved the problem by removing the PPA that caused the conflict. In my specific case, I was able to install the same software from Ubuntu repositories, so I don't need that PPA anymore.