# How do I remove Opera Residue GPG errors

Tags: updates, opera

Update I just figured out put whatever documents you have into a folder or folders with name you will not forget put on a 5 dollar USB from Dollarama. Get another two USBs or old used ones of about 8 Gb flash the.iso for Ubuntu 22.04.2 and Ubuntu-Mate 22.04.2 then change your bios with the F1 key to allow USB to first boot, then disable security boot settings. Then with the Ubuntu-mate flashed boot USBs stuck in, start computer up and press the F12 key when booting up to use the arrows to select USB boot first. The F12 boot key is different on different brands, find out which one is yours. Select a complete formate and new install wiping everything out including the Opera garbage. Then a second boot with Ubuntu 22.04.2 for a 2nd OS. Less geek and more practical way of doing it!!! The last OS is the default one. I say if the hard drive is huge over 1 or 2 tera bits and more OS to learn more stuff at your own non geek pace. I am really stupid an naive and this seemed to work for me with less involment from goofs as was my second question reply that got me the boot.

What exactly do I do to remove what is left of Opera? It seems to be causing Software Updater & Automatic Updater failure. The automatic updater now states: Failed to upload package list. This is a serious problem...... "Clearly" the previous answers did not work!!! but thanks for the help anyhow from those that tried. It just seems worse now The previous answers from two previous questions did not work,  for updating. I just copy and paste. Remember previously I stated Synaptic Package manager and Snaps have deleted Opera.

Is windows 11 or Ubuntu-Mate 22.04.2 just need a clean install, is that the solution? I say windows 11 because that is what the laptop came with. Windows does not work either as partitions where moved so the CD of Ubuntu 18.04 would load. I was trying a duel boot but it did not work. PS the first answer the (ls) part was omitted, so it was not quite correct either the (rm) did nothing when copy and pasted as stated in first question answer did not do anything either!! I am not a techie person and only copy and paste what I am given don't know to do anything else.  Just below is copy and paste from terminal.

---

W: GPG error: https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 24A1004B1F11DCC9
E: The repository 'https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

---

This question page won't let me post links that form part of the results formed in terminal (copy and paste that has links in it) This Ask a Question page states too many links. More hassle? This all seems pretty pointless. Who could work and have time for this Tom Foolery with Ubuntu Ask A Question? I guess I am going to get censored again like before for stating this like the Russian, Chinese(CCP)conspiracy joke in question 2 that was edited out by someone?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove apt repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233064/remove-apt-repository)

Comment: remove/disable the source.. Official documentation is https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu, you can edit your source and add a "#" at the start of the line to **disable** the source, do it via GUI etc... Where the source was added will depend on where you actually added it though (either `sources.list` OR inside a file in `sources.list.d/` inside `/etc/apt/`

Comment: You lost me there, I am not a techie. I Don't really understand your answer. I just had a old bootable CD with 18.04 LTS  then updated to 22.04.2. There was a link upon searching for Opera via Firefox and Duckduck Go.  I copied and pasted the link in terminal and everything worked good for a while then Opera auto updated to version 100.0.485.20_amd64 and 100.0.485.21_amd64 then the Software Updater stopped working that is it and it seems the auto-updater has stopped to. I used 12.04 LTS with mate after that came out while using Opera as it appeared to be faster. If resolved no Opera products.

Comment: I do not nee short hand just exact copy and paste fix solution does not work x@x-ThinkPad-E560:~$ sources.list
sources.list: command not found
x@x-ThinkPad-E560:~$ sources.list.d/
bash: sources.list.d/: No such file or directory
x@x-ThinkPad-E560:~$ /etc/apt/
bash: /etc/apt/: Is a directory
x@x-ThinkPad-E560:~$

Answer (score 0):

https://deb.opera.com/manual.html

```
wget -qO- https://deb.opera.com/archive.key | gpg --dearmor | sudo dd of=/usr/share/keyrings/opera-browser.gpg
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/opera-browser.gpg] https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/ stable non-free" | sudo dd of=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-archive.list
```