public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY
I am running UBUNTU 23.04 and trying to update it in order to upgrade tot 24.04lts.
During the process I get several times the below mentioned error message. The upgrade is then aborted.
Why do I get this error message and what can I do about it ?
The error message :
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key
is not available: NO_PUBKEY 24A1004B1F11DCC9

The process aborts and then the next error message is displayed:
A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of 
network problem, please check your network connection and retry.

The number at the end of the message is always the same.
I tried this:
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.quickbuild.pearsoncomputing.net --recv-keys 24A1004B1F11DCC9

With as result: gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data
What can I try more?

Note: Ubuntu 23.04 has reached the end of its life/Standard Support. Does this answer your question? How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?

This question is similar to: How do I fix the GPG error "NO_PUBKEY"?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I do not know why, you think the key you need would be on keyserver.quickbuild.pearsoncomputing.net? It is obviously not.
Try
$ sudo apt-key remove 24A1004B1F11DCC9
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 24A1004B1F11DCC9
$ sudo apt-get update

And continue your update process.

This did not work, the same error keeps occurring....

The error is: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 24A1004B1F11DCC9

The key belongs to the Opera browser. I have tried to remove Opera from my system which seems to have been successful (using the Ubuntu software app). After that, I checked removal by the command  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y [sudo] password for pieter: E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable: /usr/share/keyrings/opera-browser.gpg != /usr/share/keyrings/opera.gpg E: The list of sources could not be read  (sorry, I don't get the format of this block right)

It's a little difficult to guess where your key belongs to. Online search shows it might be from opera which you installed on your system.
As @Nikolaj suggested you can ask the ubuntu keyserver to retrieve the key.
Or you could download the missing key from Opera directly: https://deb.opera.com/archive.key

See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1475308/how-do-i-remove-opera-residue-gpg-errors/1475588#1475588

Thanks Joe, I think I managed to do that, but how to install that key then?

It depends in which format the key is. Usually it's "armored", So what you would need to do:

dearmoer it
cat KEY_FILE | gpg --dearmoer -o /usr/share/keyrings/opera-keyring.gpg
where KEY_FILE is the file you downloaded. The option -o specifies where the dearmored key will be safed. The path above is a suggestion from my side.
Add the following in front of the existing line refeering to opera in /etc/apt/source.list

deb [signed-by=/user/share/keyrings/opera.gpg] https://XXXXXXXX
WHere XXX is the existing stuff in the file.

I tried all of the above mentioned measures but the error persists. The error message when trying to upgrade is:  E:Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable: /usr/share/keyrings/opera-browser.gpg != /usr/share/keyrings/opera.gpg, E:The list of sources could not be read.
